# Optimal way for calc histogram in tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow.js

I need to calc histogram from big 1D tensor with tensorflow.js. I found way to do it, but its not optimal because of hi memory cosumtion in oneHot operation. My code example below:

```
 for (let index = 0; index < 50; index++) { //repeat some times to ensure no memory leaks
   const hist = getnormalHist(index);
   const histArray = (await hist.array()) as number[];
   const values = histArray.map((v, i) => ({ index: i, value: v }));
   await tfvis.render.barchart({ name: "hist" }, values);
 }

 function getnormalHist(seed: number) {
   return tf.tidy(() => {
     const rand = tf
       .randomNormal([100000], 0, 100, "int32", seed) //Generates long array of normal distributed randoms
       .add(500)
       .toInt();
     const oneHot = rand.oneHot(1000, 1, 0); // convert to oneHot makes it x1000 bigger
     const hist = oneHot.transpose().sum(1); // finally get histogram tensor
     return hist;
   });
 }
```

I need to make this code faster and with less memory consumption, but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the best solution that i found is:

```
const counts = 100000;
const channels = 1000;
const rand = tf.randomNormal([counts], 500, 100, "int32");
const hist = tf.sparseToDense(rand, tf.onesLike(rand), [channels], 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tf.randomNormal([100000], 0, 100, "int32", seed) //Generates long array of normal distributed randoms
       .add(500)
       .toInt()
```

The above operation generates a sample distribution with mean around 500. It can be generated using mean 500 instead of 0. The add operation is not necessary for that. Additionnally it is redundant to use `toInt` since the dtype is already `int32`. Thus it can be simplified this way:

```
tf.randomNormal([100000], 500, 100, "int32", seed)
```

It is redundant to specify 0 and 1 onvalue and offvalue as they are default value.

```
rand.oneHot(1000)
```

There is no need to transpose before computing the sum for each indice. Computing the sum over the 0 axis will count each index. An intermediate matrix of size 100000 * 1000 will no longer be used.

```
oneHot.sum(0)
```

As a summary, getNormalHist will look as the following:

```
function getnormalHist(seed: number) {
   return tf.tidy(() => {
     const rand = tf
       .randomNormal([100000], 500, 100, "int32", seed) //Generates long array of normal distributed randoms

     const oneHot = rand.oneHot(1000); // convert to oneHot makes it x1000 bigger
     const hist = oneHot.sum(0); // finally get histogram tensor
     return hist;
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggested improvements. But in this case, the most serious problem is the huge amount of memory consumed after using the OneHot operation. I did some research and came to the conclusion that in this case, the best solution would be to make a custom WebGL operation.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is create custom webGL operation.

```
class HistProgram {
  variableNames = ["X"];
  outputShape: number[];
  userCode: string;

  constructor(numIndices: number, counts: number) {
    this.outputShape = [numIndices];
    this.userCode = `
      void main() {
        int ch = getOutputCoords();
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ${counts}; i++){
            if(ch == int(getX(i))){
                c++;
            }
        }
        setOutput(float(c));
      }
    `;
  }
}
```

Now i can use it in this way:

```
const counts = 100000;
const channels = 1000;
const rand = tf.randomNormal([counts], 500, 100, "int32")
const prog = new HistProgram(channels, counts);
const hist = await tf.backend().compileAndRun(prog, [rand]).array();
```